# Generalized Notion of Krylov Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, free-modules

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and let $x_0 \in \mathcal{X} \setminus \{0_{\mathcal{X}}\}$ (here, $0_{\mathcal{X}}$ denotes the zero vector in $\mathcal{X}$). We denote by $\textrm{End}(\mathcal{X}),$ the following set:
$$ \textrm{End}(\mathcal{X}) = \{ T : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{X} \, | \, T~\textrm{is linear} \}. $$
Traditionally (and as defined by J. S. Golan in "The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know" (3ed) - Page 297), for any $T \in \textrm{End}(\mathcal{X})$ with $T^{0} \equiv \textrm{Id}_{\mathcal{X}}$ (the identity operator on $\mathcal{X}$), the subspace
$$ \mathscr{K}(x_0, T) = \textrm{span}\{ x_0, T x_0, T^{2} x_0, \dots \} = \textrm{span}\{ T^{n} x_0 \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $$
is called the $\textit{Krylov subspace}$ of $\mathcal{X}$ defined by $T$ and $x_0$ (here, for any $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \},$ $T^{k} \equiv \underset{k~\textrm{times}}{\underbrace{T \circ T \circ \cdots \circ T}}$). Additionally, for any strictly positive integer $m,$ we also write

$$\mathscr{K}_{m}(x_0, T) = \textrm{span}\{ x_0, T x_0, T^{2} x_0, \dots, T^{m-1} x_0 \} \subset \mathcal{X}.$$

$\textbf{Question}$:

Is there a generalized notion of this collection? For example, if I relax the assumption of $\mathcal{X}$ being a vector space to $\mathcal{X}$ being a free module, then can I say something about the set $\mathscr{K}(x_{0}, T)$ (is it a submodule in this case)? Do a significant majority (if not all) of the expected properties that we see in the former case carry over to the latter? Any assistance in understanding this topic (whether it be a definitive answer, or references that I could read to figure these things out for myself) is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Dealing with modules is hard, even if your module is finitely generated, submodules are not necessarily finitely generated, plus the notion of basis is not defined.

Comment: Also you should try splitting your questions in 2 separate posts, it could be easier for us to give separate answers to each question, also the first paragraph of your second question seems confused. However these are good questions

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to clear up my question and perhaps separate them. For the second question, it's similar to the idea of a Cartesian product. For example, I know that if $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{Y} = \mathbb{C}^n,$ then I can write $\mathcal{Y} = \underset{n~\textrm{times}}{\underbrace{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \times \cdots \times \mathcal{X}}}.$ Granted, in this case, this is a purely set-theoretical notion. Just wondering if I can do something similar (or in a similar realm) for the example illustrated above.

Comment: Also, I was under the impression that free modules do, indeed, have a basis (or set of free generators). Am I misinterpreting something here? Or are you referring to the so-called submodule. In which case, my apologies.

Comment: Yes I was referring to submodules, Even if $\mathcal{X}$ is a finite rank free module, your Krylov space is the module generated by the $T^n x, n \in \mathbb{N}$ which means it is just a submodule of your module, hence not necessarily finitely generated. Also yes basis works for free modules but only for free modules. In general unicity is a big problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be sufficient to you, but there are no such generalization (that I know) of Krylov spaces to modules. Why? I can think of several reasons:

- What would be the purpose of these? Are they useful for reduction? Is reduction even a thing for modules endomorphism?
- A ring $R$ is not necessarily a domain, hence you don't have factorisation of polynomials in it. Let us suppose we add this hypothesis ($ab = 0 \implies a = 0 \text{ or } b = 0$).
- Defining the determinant requires us to have a notion of dimension and a bimodule $M$ (and not just module) then we would have
  $$\det: \bigwedge\nolimits_R^n (M) \to R$$
  Which would require a choice, but the choice would not be relevant since our ring is a domain and we only need to be able to tell when it is zero.
- Imagining that it is the case, we would have well defined characteristic function but would it be a polynomial? One should look into the $R$-algebra $\operatorname{End}(M)$, it may be possible but it is to check.
- Even so, a Krylov space is defined with $x \in V$ and $T \in \hom(V,V)$ by
  $$K(x,T) : \operatorname{Span}\{T^n x , \, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
  We can choose a finite number of these spanning vectors since we have a finite dimension, but replace everything with module vocabulary, you get $K(x,T)$ as a submodule of a finite rank free module $V$, but it is not necessarily finitely generated and even if it is, it doesn't necessarily have a basis, since it is not necessarily free.

In summary, a lot of reasons, but maybe you could try to invent a new theory that takes the things into account? I can't know for sure.

Comment: This is a very thoughtful response, and I'll certainly have to find ways to account for the points you've made when I continue to look into the topic.